# print selected indexes in a python list

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

In this scenario, due to selection criteria, I have come up with the following list:

```
allowed_max = [21, 21, 21, 18, 16, 17, 22, 36, 36, 36, 34, 34, 13, 13, 13, 12, 26, 26, 28, 28, 28, 27, 26]
```

When, I index the list in reference to it's original list, using the command below;

```
index_max = [data_series.index(i) for i in allowed_max]
```

Upon printing the list, I will get the following values:

```
index_max = [5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 14, 15, 16, 16, 16, 18, 18, 26, 26, 26, 27, 32, 32, 34, 34, 34, 35, 32]
```

Now, I only want the values in the list that are equivalent to the pattern width, which in this scenario is three.

```
pattern_width = 3
```

So, in this scenario, the values I would want to take out of the list and append in a new list are 5, 16, 26, and 34.
What command should I use to obtain the final answer?

```
final_answer = [5, 16, 26, 34]
```

Note: I am not allowed to use numpy. Thanks!

Comment: So `index_max` is not sorted and you don't want `final_answer` to contain 32 since its third entry occurs too late at the end of the list?

Comment: Oh, I do not want 32 as it is does not occur concurrently as compared to the values in the final answer

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over `index_max` and check equality between the current item and the following two items:

```
final_answer = [
    index_max[i]
    for i in range(len(index_max)-2)
    if index_max[i] == index_max[i+1] == index_max[i+2]
]
```

Alternatively, if order doesn't matter and you just want to *count* the items, you can use a `Counter` object:

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(index_max)
final_answer = [ key for key, val in counter.items() if val == 3 ]
```

(The second solution yields `[5, 16, 26, 32, 34]` - not exactly what you asked for.)